# jackson jsonnode property error

Tags: java, jackson, dropwizard

I want something like this

```
@Property
public JsonNode node
```

To be able to pass in directly from the rest api client.

This works in Jackson 1.9 (with no special serialization), but not in 2.1 for some reason. I get an error that says JsonNode can't be deserialized.

I created a class that implements the MessageBodyReader interface, but I'm not sure how to actually use it. How do I make this work?

Are there other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

Turns out I was using the wrong JsonNode from org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty when I should be using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty